# Resources.LoadAll загружает из AppData/Local

Tags: c#, unity3d

Resources.LoadAll грузит изображения из другой директории.

1. Создал папку Resources в Assets.
2. Поместил туда изображения .png, texture type - "Sprite", "Multiple", packing tag "dragon".
3. Код:

   ```
   public Sprite[] spriteArray;

   void Start ()
   {
       spriteArray = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("dragon"); 
   }
   ```

В результате изображения подгружаются не из Assets\Resources, а из:
AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\com.unity.package-manager-ui@1.8.8\Editor\Resources

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуй помнить название своей папки

Comment: @RodGers поменял, все равно не грузит. Пробовал поместить новую директорию внутри Resources, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New_directory/dragon"), но не работает.

Comment: Попробуй одиночный Load

Comment: Одиночный работает, но массив нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ты забыл привести тип к Sprite.

```
 public Sprite[] sprites;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("dragon");
    Debug.Log(sprites.Length);
}
```

Comment: `<Sprite>` не отображалось, потому что его съел парсер (я поправил форматирование в вопросе). Да и вообще суть не в этом.